# Does the number of Grifts done affect the drop rates of the next ones?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have been farming as much greater rift boss to get the gems / legendary. So I was waiting until below 4 minutes to make sure I get the next level key.

I was running with my friends and some of them were saying : "I don't know what happened but I was seeing much more legendary from the Greater rift boss before".

I was just wondering if it was just sheer luck that they don't get much or if once you complete X number of greater rifts the drop rates lower or something. Or maybe the completion time increases drop rate. I don't know, was there any blue post on this?

Thanks

Comment: Looking for developer information is off-topic.  Most likely what you're seeing is confirmation bias.

Comment: Unless they patched the game since, it's just bad luck

Comment: You should change your question to ask if the number Grifts done affect the drop rates of the next ones. Also, are you doing the same or lower level GRifts? Unsure if level does affect drops (been said not but no one knows for sure yet).

Comment: I've been running from 1 to 16 or so. And yea this is basically what I'm asking just not wording it the right way I guess sorry

Comment: I am not aware of the completion time affecting drop rates of the items from greater rift bosses.

Comment: From observation they seem to have lowered the drop rate of items from the greater rift guardians when the community event stopped. No post to cite so this is just musings.

Comment: I think I will create a google doc excel sheet and insert my Grift data in it to investigate

Comment: To close-voters:  ["Knowledge only a developer could have" is not the same as "Developer intent"](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/is-this-question-requires-developer-only-knowledge-the-same-thing-as-developer).  Indeed, we've had **many** questions that *"only a developer could know,"* which have been satisfactorily answered using Science™!  Just check most of the top-questions list.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's less, "only a developer could know", and more the last line: "I don't know, was there any blue post on this?".  That's developer intent, down to a tee.

Comment: Blue post is only for confirmation on Blizzard part, which can be from a Community manager, not a dev (let's not argue about it being similar, it is and it isn't). That said, this question is fine as it's now asking about a possible difference between running 1 GRift vs running X in a row upgrading your key.

Comment: Developers read StackExchange...

Comment: It seems to me that the higher grift you have completed, the worse drops you get at grifts significantly lower than that level.